# Recursive function in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I need to make a recursive function that takes an object and a vector and returns a list of all the objects that preceded my object parameter.

I did it using iteration like this:

```
(define (precedes obj vec)
  (do ((i 1 (+ i 1))
      (list '() (if (eqv? obj (vector-ref vec i))
            (cons(vector-ref vec (- i 1)) list)
            list)))
    ((= i (vector-length vec)) list))
)
```

but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to do the same thing using recursion. I'm confused how I can keep incrementing through the vector as I recursively call. So far, all I have is this:

```
(define (precedes2 obj vec)
  (define list '())
  (if (eqv? obj (vector-ref vec i))
      (cons(vector-ref vec(- i 1)) list)
      list)))
```

I figured I would use the same logic I used before in terms of the if statement, but I'm not sure how to now call the same function with the updated vector. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the interesting position of moving from an iterative implementation to a recursive one;  usually people go in the other direction.  Fortunately, moving from a **do**-loop to recursion is pretty easy.  In general, a **do** loop can be rewritten as follows:

```
(do ((i i-init i-step)
     (j j-init j-step)
     ...)
    (test result)
  body)
```

becomes

```
(define f (i j ...)
  (cond
    (test result)
    (else body (f i-step j-step ...))))

(f i-init j-init ...)
```

That translation is usually written using a named let, though:

```
(let f ((i i-init)
        (j j-init)
        ...)
  (cond
    (test result)
    (else body (f i-step j-step ...))))
```

So (and I haven't tested the code) your original function

```
(define (precedes obj vec)
  (do ((i 1 (+ i 1))
      (list '() (if (eqv? obj (vector-ref vec i))
            (cons(vector-ref vec (- i 1)) list)
            list)))
    ((= i (vector-length vec)) list))
)
```

would turn into

```
(define (precedes obj vec)
  (let loop ((i 1)
             (list '()))
    (cond
      ((= i (vector-length vec)) list)
      (else (loop (+ i 1)
                  (if (eqv? obj (vector-ref vec i))
                      (cons (vector-ref vec (- i 1)) list)
                      list))))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the details on the logic as well. Really helped me understand the language a lot better. Only just started coding in Scheme like 2 weeks ago.

Comment: @Ganda As I mentioned at the beginning, this is a rather interesting case because it's often easier to write the recursive version, and then (in Common Lisp, which doesn't necessarily have tail call elimination) write a version using do.  It's less common to go in the other direction, I think.